# Why cant I see the all 3 ImageButtons on the same row?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout (which I could include in other layouts), which contains 3 Image buttons (back, menu, forward).

Those 3 Image buttons should be on the same line (because later I would include this layout to other layouts in the bottom of each layout)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I can't see the all 3 Buttons, and they are not in the same row (same horizontal line)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:background="@drawable/HomButton"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuForward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forward"
        android:background="@drawable/forward_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the code that goes around this as well?

Comment: Please add the full layout xml.

Comment: "a layout"? which layout? Hope you know Android itself has few predefined layouts.

Comment: Post the complete layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it won't fit because it looks like some of your images are way too big, but we can proportionally weight it so it'll fit.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuBack"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuMenu"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:background="@drawable/HomButton"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuForward"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forward"
        android:background="@drawable/forward_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

using `weightSum` and `layout_weight`, 3 and 1, we ensure they all each take 1/3 of the space in your linearlayout (oh, and layout_width is 0 because layout_weight overrides it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout with orientation as "horizontal". This will make all the views appear in a row. This LinearLayout can reside as a nested layout inside a another layout, like for example RelativeLayout. You can use this layout design by importing it in other XMLlayouts too.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back"
        android:background="@drawable/back_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:background="@drawable/HomButton"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttomMenuForward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forward"
        android:background="@drawable/forward_button"
        android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems like the image size is too large to fit in the screen. Ideal image sizes for Android devices should be like 36x36, 48x48, 72x72 or 96x96, depending on different screen sizes. Android studio provides an option to format your images for different screen sizes.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like different sized images.
Assuming you have these in a horizontal linear layout; Try changing the height to a fixed dp and put the weight to 1 for all three imagebuttons

Example:

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/buttomMenuBack"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:text="Back"
android:background="@drawable/back_button"
android:onClick="onClickButtomMenu"/>
```

If you do this for all three imagebuttons, they will fill the screen and all be the same height, right beside each other.